# C# Mono Linux Process Output

Tags: c#, linux, process, mono, raspberry-pi

Running a c# console application compiled in visual studio 2013 on a Raspberry Pi(Linux) with Mono installed, the following code...

```
System.Diagnostics.Process syncProc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
syncProc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
syncProc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
syncProc.StartInfo.FileName = "bash";
syncProc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-c sync --help";
syncProc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
syncProc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
syncProc.Start();
String stdOutput = syncProc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
String errorOutput = syncProc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
syncProc.WaitForExit();

if (syncProc.ExitCode == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("SOUTPUT: " + stdOutput);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("EOUTPUT: " + errorOutput);

    throw new Exception("Failed to sync with exit code: " + syncProc.ExitCode);
}
```

...outputs "SOUTPUT: "

Why is stdOutput always empty?

Comment: What's the output if you run `bash -c sync --help` from the console yourself?

Comment: There is no output. However "sync --help" shows:
Usage: sync [OPTION]
Force changed blocks to disk, update the super block.

      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit

Comment: Well, there's your answer: stdOutput is empty because the command you're executing does not output anything.

Comment: If I am to understand the command by comparing to windows. To open command prompt B with arguments from command prompt A will show output for B inside B, not A.
Is it not the same in this case? By opening a separate terminal with with arguments, the output is not going to be shown by default, as the separate terminal is the one receiving output? Does it not need to be redirected? To the terminal spawning the separate terminal?

Answer (score 0):

You could try redirecting the whole output asynchronously like this:

```
syncProc.ErrorDataReceived += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("EOUTPUT:{0}", e.Data);
syncProc.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("SOUTPUT:{0}", e.Data);
syncProc.Start();
syncProc.BeginErrorReadLine();
syncProc.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why is stdOutput always empty?

The arguments are passed wrongly. The `-c` option's commands must be contained in a single argument *command_string*:

```
syncProc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-c 'sync --help'";
```